# How do I set up a VPN in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn

I would like to set up my network/internet connection to connect to a VPN so added security while online.  I am using Ubuntu Linux 10.04.  I have tried itshidden but it will either not stay connected or fail to connect all together.  How do I go about doing this in plain english?  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a VPN provider:
System -> Preferences -> Network Connections -> Tab "VPN" -> Add

If not, try browsing through the [Tor network](http://www.torproject.org/overview.html).

> Tor is a network of virtual tunnels
>   that allows people and groups to
>   improve their privacy and security on
>   the Internet. It also enables software
>   developers to create new communication
>   tools with built-in privacy features.
>   Tor provides the foundation for a
>   range of applications that allow
>   organizations and individuals to share
>   information over public networks
>   without compromising their privacy.
>
> Tor does not magically encrypt all of
>   your Internet activities. Understand
>   what Tor does and does not do for you.

Comment: I am trying to follow the instructions and I keep getting permissions issues.  I am the one who set all this up, yet it will not let me change permissions as a user and I do not know enough about the command line to do this as root.  Why cant this be simple through a GUI?

Answer (score 0):

As [BloodPhilia](https://superuser.com/users/34844/bloodphilia) says, you doit on

> System -> Preferences -> Network Connections -> Tab "VPN" -> Add

But I used It's hidden for a while and they have really low priority for free accounts, I believe that if you pay for an account your connection will be more stable.